# how to fix div with respect to parent div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have parent div and 7 child div and I want two divs to fix to the extreme of the parent div and do not move with respect to parent div but move along with parent div (it means that if I change the padding of the body the arrangement of divs should remain the same). And rest of 5 div to scroll in the x direction in parent div.

but the problem is that in my code fix div remain fixed to window or scroll along with other div.

Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t0ek1tfg/3/).

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test6</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test6.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="list">
    <div class="button button-left"></div>
    <div class="button button-right"></div>
    <div class="card">      
    </div>
    <div class="card">      
    </div>
    <div class="card">      
    </div>
    <div class="card">      
    </div>
    <div class="card">      
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    margin-top: 200px;

}
.list{
    width: 1100px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: relative;

}
.button{
    display: table;
    top: 150px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: rgba(100, 100, 200, 0.8);
        position: absolute;
        /*position: fixed;*/
}
.button-left{
    left: calc(50% - 550px);
    border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0 ;
}
.button-right{
    right: calc(50% - 550px);
    border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;
}
.card{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 360px;
    width:250px;
    margin: 20px 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #505050;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1100px){
    .button-left{
        left: 0;
    }
    .button-right{
        right: calc(100% - 1100px);

    }
}
```

Comment: use position for both the div and set it.

Comment: but it doesn't work,( margin:0 auto;) stops working on the parent div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap your `.list` element inside a container and add an extra div for your controls. Set the position rule of the extra div for the controls to `relative` that way you can keep the control buttons absolute positioned. The controls contain does not need to be a child of the list itself.

Here is an example

```css
body{
  margin-top: 200px;

}
.list {
  width: 1100px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
}
.controls {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: +1;
}
.button {
  display: table;
  top: 150px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(100, 100, 200, 0.8);
  position: absolute;
  /*position: fixed;*/
}
.button-left {
  left: calc(50% - 550px);
  border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0 ;
}
.button-right {
  right: calc(50% - 550px);
  border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;
}

.card{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 360px;
  width:250px;
  margin: 20px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #505050;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1100px){
  .button-left{
    left: 0;
  }
  .button-right{
    right: calc(100% - 1100px);

  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="controls">
    <div class="button button-left"></div>
    <div class="button button-right"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="list">
    <div class="card">  
    </div>
    <div class="card">  
    </div>
    <div class="card">  
    </div>
    <div class="card">  
    </div>
    <div class="card">  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

All the `.cards` div should be a child of another div, here I have added a `.cardcontainer` div so that parent div should have 3 childs, 2 buttons and `card container`. Also, need to use `display: -webkit-box` in `.cardcontainer`.

Also, I have set the `width` of `.cardcontainer to`90%`, you can chnage it accordingly.

`scroll` css should be in `.cardconatiner` div, not in the `.list` div

```css
.cardcontainer {
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
  display: -webkit-box;
}

.list {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.button {
  top: 150px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(100, 100, 200, 0.8);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.button-left {
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
}

.button-right {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;
}

.card {
  /*display: inline-block;*/
  height: 360px;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 20px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #505050;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1100px) {
  .button-left {
    left: 0;
  }
  .button-right {
    right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="list">
    <div class="button button-left"></div>
    <div class="button button-right"></div>
    <div class="cardcontainer">
      <div class="card">
      </div>
      <div class="card">
      </div>
      <div class="card">
      </div>
      <div class="card">
      </div>
      <div class="card">
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```